# What could "Haselünne" mean?

Tags: etymology, place-name

I traced back my lineage on my dad’s side to a little town called *Haselünne.* I never bothered to look up what in meant until now, and now, I’m really curious.

From my research, I’m going to guess that *Hase* would obviously come from the town’s vicinity to the river Hase, which in turn came from the Germanic *haswa,* meaning *grey.*

But *lünne?* I have absolutely no clue. The [town's website](http://www.haseluenne.de/index.php/de/), contains the word *luenne*, probably because an umlaut would reduce site visits and/or perhaps the *ue* would effectively represent the *ü,* or because something using *haselunne* was already taken. Who knows, but either way, sticking *luenne* into Google Translate returns *Lünne.*

So here I am, hoping someone has a theory that would give this town the other half of its name! *Grey [something],* or rather, *[something] of the Hase.* Perhaps that *Lünne* is someone's name. I am not very verbose in German yet, so I am left to guessing.

Comment: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haselünne - First paragraph in the Geschichte section. In short: passage across dark water.

Comment: @Eller, unfortunately that paragraph on Wikipedia is without references.

Comment: In situations where an *ü* is not available it is to be replaced by *ue*, never by *u*.

Comment: Additional: [Wikipedia Lünne](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%BCnne): Lunne: altnord. hlunne = Rolle; a place at a river, where goods are transported over the river using underlying woods

Comment: @Eller comments are not intended to be used for answers, or partial answers, since they may be deleted during database housekeeping.

Comment: Thank you a ton or all these great comments! It seems finding the name of a little town is more involved than I thought.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the article [about Haselünne on German Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasel%C3%BCnne#Geschichte) name "Haselünne" means "passage across dark water", where "hase" comes from "*hassa*" (= "dark water") and "*lünne*" is derived from "*lunni/lunne*".

> Im nahen Flusslauf wurde durch Einlegen von Rundhölzern eine Furt errichtet. Diese Rundhölzer hießen „lunni“ und sie gaben dem Ort den Namen „Lunni“, „Lunne“ und mit der Flussbezeichnung „Hassa“ = dunkles Wasser = Hase schließlich den Namen Haselünne.

The linked article says that "*lunne*" was the word for round wooden timber (which was used for building a passage across the river). However, [another article](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%BCnne) (about village Lünne which is about 30 km away from Haselünne) states that "lunne" (altnord. *hlunne* = *Rolle*)* was a name for  passage itself. But is it passage or timber - I don't think it changes much in this case.

---

**Thanks to IQV for the comment*.

Comment: Thanks a ton for the research! It never occurred to me to check the German Wikipedia... d'oh.

It seems I can't escape dark/black and water in my family line: my nearest Scottish clan is a sept of Clan Douglas, which took its name from the village, Douglas, in Lanarkshire. This in turn took its name from the Douglas Water, originating from the Scots word "Dùghlas", which means "dark stream", or "black water". Also, that sept is Clan BLACKwood. Lol